# Two inline divs will not obey width

Tags: html, css

I'm not really sure what's going on here because I cannot position two divs inline as they will not obey a width rule.

`col3` is set to 40% width and the way I understand it, the child elements should be able to use 100% of that space.

How can I set `.small-left` and `.small-right`, each with a 15px padding, inline?

Here is my code:

```
#content #col3 {
padding-left: 15px;
width: 40%;
}

.double .small-left {
display:inline;
width:50% !important;
display:inline-block;
padding-right:15px;
border-right:1px solid #E2E2E2 !important;
}

.double .small-right {
display:inline;
width:50% !important;
border:none !important;
display:inline-block;
padding-left:15px;
}

<div class="double">
  <div class="small-left">111</div>
  <div class="small-right">111</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you using `display:inline;` *and* `display: inline-block`? It's one or the other, and the later one wins.

Comment: Yeah, that's a mistake. I need to remove the inline. I'll do that now.

Comment: Meager, I now have the divs obeying the width but they are on top of one another. If I lower the width, they will go inline. So, how do I get both divs to take up all the space?

Comment: @NaN please check my answer to fix this issue with the elements piling up each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `display:inline-block` from the css part.

Here is the Demo :[fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jvaibhav/7tPs8/)

```
.double .small-left {
display:inline;
width:50% !important;
padding-right:15px;
border-right:1px solid #E2E2E2 !important;
}

.double .small-right {
display:inline;
width:50% !important;
border:none !important;
padding-left:15px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I see that works. How do I get both divs to take up all the space?

Comment: you can use either float:right to the right div and float:left to the left OR you can use box-sizing: border-box

Comment: Thank you. I'm still struggling with the width issue. I just tried using floats on both elements and everything goes out of alignment.

Comment: You have padding 15px and width 50% for both the divs so the width will become more than 100% with the padding. Try to make the divs to 45% width with the float properties.

Comment: @NaN : Check this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/jvaibhav/7tPs8/1/ So the padding and div width must not be more than 100%.

Comment: OK, I just did that and it does work now, however, I was just curious how this is normally handled. When there is padding in px like this and percentages used on the elements, how does one account for the padding? Is it ok to just use 45% like in this case or is there a better way?

Comment: @NaN: It is good approach that make your padding also in the format of percentage with the width of div so you can easily manipulate the total width. you can make 49% div size and .5% padding: check this: http://jsfiddle.net/jvaibhav/7tPs8/2/

Comment: I see that. You're right and I can see how using percentages would help me here. I will go back and change them. Thank you for this advice.

Comment: @NaN : If you are using CSS3 compliant browser than in that case you can use calc function like width: calc(50% - 15px);. In this case easy to apply the width in percentage and padding in pixels.

Answer (score 0):

You can't apply width to `inline` elements.

Either you have to use `display: block` or `display: inline-block`. For the problem that you mentioned in your comment add the following:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

Comment: Thanks. Will this allow both divs to use all the space within the parent container?

Comment: Your `width: 50%;` will do that.. Adding the `box-sizing: border-box;` along with the other styles will make sure that the `padding` is assigned from the existing width of the elements

Comment: Wow, thank you for that explanation! I had no idea that's what it was for. So, I just added box-sizing: border-box; to both elements but they are still one on top of the other.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the display: inline and display: inline-block and add the following rule:

```
.double > div {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks DRD. I used your rule and unfortunately, the floats are throwing everything else out of alignment.

Comment: Yes, you have to clear the floats.  Apply the clearfix class to the container within which you are floating the elements: http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/.

Answer (score 0):

The padding and border and is also included in the blocks width. So if you you have a container that is 100px and set its width to 50% with 15px padding the actual width will be 65px. You can fix this by setting the padding to a percentage.

```
.double .small-left {
    width:40%;
    display:inline-block;
    padding-right:9%;
    border-right:1px solid #E2E2E2 ;
}

.double .small-right {
    width:40%;
    border:none;
    display:inline-block;
    padding-left:10%;
}
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/78xt9/2/